# Facebook SDK: Authenticate requests so the php server knows it's coming from a logged in user

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have iOS and Android games that talk to my server using PHP. I have Facebook login in the games. I want to authenticate requests so the server knows it's coming from a logged in user. I found this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24077363/211457
However, with the latest version (v5) of the PHP SDK I don't see this method:

```
$facebook->setAccessToken($token);.
```

https://github.com/facebook/facebook-php-sdk-v4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass a default access token to the SDK at initalization, see https://developers.facebook.com/docs/php/Facebook#config

```
'default_access_token' => '{access-token}',
```

Also, you can specify the access token to be used with each individual [`FacebookRequest`](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/php/FacebookRequest/5.0.0) directly.

Answer (score 1):

The only thing you should use the Facebook token for is to access certain resources from the Facebook servers.

Theoretically, each time the user makes a request to your own server and supplies this Facebook token, you could verify its validity by passing it over to Facebook and seeing if their servers will accept it - however this would double or triple the amount of time it takes for each request to your server.

The best approach is to leave the Facebook token only for Facebook requests, and generate a separate token for any requests against your own server. This token is stored in your database for quick look ups to see whether a request should be authenticated.

Comment: thanks for the information, even though the other answer was accepted, I plan to use your recommendation as well.